# Daily rolling with limit for backup files with logj4

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

Im usign log4j2 for logging. I need daily logging with keeping a backup of 5 days logs. My log4j2.xml looks as below. My backup files keep on increasing in number eventhough ive limited the number to 5. Where did i go wrong??

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Configuration status="trace" monitorInterval="300">
    <Appenders>

  <RollingFile name="roll-by-time-and-size"
  fileName="C:\\Users\\ann\\logs\\testing.log"
  filePattern="C:\\Users\\ann\\logs\\testing.%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log.gz"
  ignoreExceptions="false">
    <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %p %m%n</Pattern>
    </PatternLayout>
    <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>


    </Policies>
    <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5"/>
    <!-- <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        <Delete basePath="C:\\Users\\ann\\logs" maxDepth="1">
            <IfFileName glob="C:\\Users\\ann\\logs\\test.*.log.gz" />
            <IfLastModified age="3" />
        </Delete>
    </DefaultRolloverStrategy> -->
</RollingFile>

    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n">
      </PatternLayout>
    </Console>


  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>   

    <Root level="ALL">
      <AppenderRef ref="roll-by-time-and-size"/>
       <AppenderRef ref="Console"/> 
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: You might be better off running a script to delete older than 5 days -> `forfiles /p "\\path\goes\here" /s /m *.* /D -5 /C "cmd /c del @path"`

Comment: Does it mean tat  <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5"/> has no impact.

Comment: Are you sure the GZip compression will work on some Windows environment? If you fix your filePattern, this will solve your `DefaultRolloverStrategy` parameter and make it work properly

Comment: i got it correctly zipped when i set the rolling for every minute and the backup was indexed correctly based on the count provided. The index is not working when i tried to backup on a daily basis.

Comment: i even tried the <delete tag option which is commented in the above code, but tat too dint delete files older than the count mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `max` consider using the `delete` rule.

Comment: How do i write a shell script to zip the files older than 5 days and move it to an archive folder?